# Cannot insert a row into a table with a select statement using the table

Tags: mysql

I want to insert a row into a table :

```
insert into menu(title, routerlink, icon, hassubmenu, parentid, alignement) 
values('Accès site', '/pages/reporting/accessite', 'reorder', 0, (select idmenu from menu where title = 'Reporting' and parentid = 0), 0);
```

When executed it gives the error `You can't specify target table 'menu' for an update in FROM clause`

So how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use INSERT .. SELECT, not INSERT .. VALUES.

```
insert into menu ( title, 
                   routerlink, 
                   icon, 
                   hassubmenu, 
                   parentid, 
                   alignement ) 
select 'Accès site', 
       '/pages/reporting/accessite', 
       'reorder', 
       0, 
       ( select idmenu 
         from menu 
         where title = 'Reporting' and parentid = 0 /* LIMIT 1 */ ), 
       0;
```

You must understand that if the subquery returns more than one row then the query will fail. So you should add `LIMIT 1` (with proper ORDER BY maybe) into it.

Comment: Can you explain why is the select option the solution for it ?

Comment: @pheromix Because in INSERT .. VALUES the expression to be inserted is evaluated during the insertion. The insertion may effect the subquery output which will effect the insertion which may effect... potential cycle, so this possibility is blocked (but you may use subquery which selects from another tables). (Really this is, of course, incorrect... sorry). In INSERT .. SELECT the complete rowset to be inserted is generated before the insertion, cyclic insertion is not possible, and this is allowed.